# Is the johnny-five library and javascipt good for Arduino projects?

Tags: node.js, johnny-five

I am new to **Arduino**. I just have my **Arduino UNO** kit and started to do some small projects with `node.js` and the `Johnny-five` library.

My question is why there not many content about `javascript`+**Arduino** in web, and the last news on `Johnny-five` website dated last year.

> Is js development still relevant for Arduino?

Comment: johnny-five makes the arduino nothing more than a peripheral for a computer ... the arduino contains a very basic code that allows the computer to send commands to the arduino .... most people want to use the arduino as a standalone system

Comment: Because Johnny-five covers about 1% of the possible use cases for an Arduino and hardly anyone uses it because of that?

Comment: js is great to use for web interfaces with the ESP chips, but it's not very good to actually program the low-power, low-ram device itself. As MCUs get more powerful, and further blur the lines between them and SBCs you will see JS as a more viable option. I would say the big obstacle now is attitude; embedded programmers don't take JS seriously. Heck, they don't even take arduino very seriously. Looking at the site, it seems that j5 only runs on expensive corporate boards that nobody wants, and ardnuio ones that are too weak and don't have wifi, and nobody wants a usb tether.